# How can I make Spinner function stop crashing my app when trying to get the selected item?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, spinner

I'm having Trouble getting string values from a spinner without it crashing my app , I want to make a choice according to the 2 pair of selected items in the when Function

```
val convertFrom = spnConvertFrom.selectedItem.toString()
val convertTo = spnConvertTo.selectedItem.toString()
val value = initialAmount.toString()
var valor2= value.toDouble()
when {
    //Condicion
    (convertFrom.equals("NIO") && convertTo.equals("USD")) -> currencyConverted.apply {
        text = "Something"
    }
    else -> Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

I've tried to switch the syntax a bit from = to .equals() (Same thing) Read something about it being null at the moment of the comparison but have no idea how to check it , I'm quite new to Kotlin and programing in android

Comment: Read here, especially "safe calls": https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html I suggest that you should read through the entire documentation. You don't need to understand it, but at least you will remember part of it when you get into trouble like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several lines which could case an NPE

1. The lines where you are retrieving the `selectedItem`. You can handle those by adding the `?` operator after the spinner instances
2. The line where you convert `value` to a `Double. You can avoid the error by using` toDoubleOrNull`and providing a default value in case that`value` is not numeric
3. The line where you set the `text` of `currencyConverted`. If it is optional you should add the `?` operator there as well:

```
 val convertFrom = spnConvertFrom?.selectedItem.toString()
 val convertTo = spnConvertTo?.selectedItem.toString()
 val value = initialAmount.toString()
 var valor2 = value.toDoubleOrNull() ?: 0.0

when {
    //Condicion
    (convertFrom.equals("NIO") && convertTo.equals("USD")) -> currencyConverted?.text = "Something"
    else -> Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```